# validate if instance exists django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a REST Api on DRF. I have a ModelViewSet endpoint from rest_framework.viewsets.

I have a Post and a Comment model. Each comment belongs to a post. So I have defined 2 endpoints, sort of:

```
1) router.register(r"posts", views.PostView
2) router.register(r"(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/comments", views.CommentView
```

Both of them inherit from ModelViewSet so I can perform CRUD operations on them.

I have a question regarding the second endpoint. Since we create comments to posts, I am getting a post pk from posts/int:pk/comments. But the problem is when I do a GET request on this endpoint it'll return the list of all comments, but I need those to belong to a post (id in url). When I try make a POST request on this endpoint if the post does not exist it raises DoesNotExist error which is logical.

What I have done so far is:

1. redefined a get_queryset() to retrieve only objects belonging to a particular post. If the post does not exist it returns an empty list (though I think it should raise 404)
2. redefined validate() in my serializer to check if the post exists. Returns 404 if it does not

But when I check PUT, DELETE, PATCH methods on posts/int:pk/comments/int:pk it won't take the post instance into consideration either i.e. it'll allow these operation even if the post does not exist which wrong I believe.

Is there a method in ModelViewSet class that gets triggered on every request and checks if the post instance exists? So that I don't have to redefine every CRUD method just to check it.

EDIT

CommentView

```
class CommentView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk2'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user, post=post)
```

Comment: Can you show your code for CommentView ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post

Comment: try removing the line `    queryset = Comment.objects.all()` it might override your definition of get_queryset. Only one of thoses is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [drf-nested-routers package](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers).

If it doesn't solve your problem, maybe what you want is standard router registration:

```
router.register(r"posts", views.PostView)
router.register(r"comments", views.CommentView)
```

and then use a package like [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to filter via query params when listing the comments: `/comments/?post=<id>`. When creating a comment just send the post id in the body of the request (don't forget to include the 'post' field in CommentSerializer)

Comment: I believe splitting the route into two and sending a post id in a body will do the job for sure. Looks like redefining get_queryset and perform_create did the job too. Thanks